# Is Kotlin Multi-platform Mobile code different from compiled Swift code on iOS platform?

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

According to docs

> Kotlin/Native is a technology for compiling Kotlin code to native
> binaries, which can run without a virtual machine. It is an LLVM based
> backend for the Kotlin compiler and native implementation of the
> Kotlin standard library.

So K/N is using LLVM to compile Kotlin code to native code for iOS. [Swift compiler also uses LLVM to optimize and generate machine code](https://swift.org/swift-compiler/#compiler-architecture).

- So is there any difference between compiled K/N vs compiled Swift code on iOS platform?

  - If so what are those differences? Performance and etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is that Kotlin code compiled for iOS brings along the Kotlin/Native runtime which establishes the Kotlin/Native memory model that aims for safe [concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/concurrency.html) and [immutability](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/immutability.html) of global objects, and also provides its own garbage collector for Kotlin objects.

Otherwise, code compiled with Kotlin/Native indeed has two-way [interoperability with Swift](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/objc_interop.html), as normally [the Kotlin binary](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-build-native-binaries.html#build-final-native-binaries) that you use on iOS is an Objective-C framework that you can [import in one project with Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis).